# How to access the XmlHttpRequest object in JSF ajax's addOnEvent callback?

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want to add a header to every AJAX request sent from every form of every page in a JSF application. In jquery I can use something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(ev, xhr, opt) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('custom-header', random-value);
});
```

But how can I do something similar in JSF 2.2?

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    // how to access the XmlHttpRequest object?
});
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint there? Did you inspect all the 'variables' that are available? Did you check the stacktrace and see if there are functions you can override?

Comment: Yes I set a breakpoint and inspected all the 'variables' but could not find anything suitable (must confess I am not very good at js)